# Putting a charged sphere in a uniform electric field - can we superpose the individual fields to find the resulting one?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

Let's say we want to find the potential outside a charged metal sphere with total charge $q$ when it is placed in a uniform magnetic field $\vec{E}_0$. Infinitely far from all other charge, the charge $q$ on the sphere will be uniformly distributed over its surface and its field $\vec{E}_q$ will be radially symmetric, as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

When the sphere is placed in the uniform field, positive charge will be moved to the top of the sphere and some negative charge will be induced at the bottom, with the net charge of course still $q$. The field will look something like this:

[image]

Does the final field $\vec{E}=\vec{E}_0+\vec{E}_q$? Griffiths, in the solution to one of his problems, assumes this without justification. However, I'm not convinced this can be done by superposition.If we use the principle of superposition we should be superposing the uniform field and the field of the redistributed charge, the latter of which is not $\vec{E}_q$. Is this understanding correct? If so, how would we go about calculating $\vec{E}$?

Comment: You're correct, you need to add the redistributed charge field and $E_0$. Are you sure Griffith did this in a conducting sphere? Because in an insulating sphere, if the charges don't move and there isn't any induced dipole this is correct.

Comment: In a uniform magnetic field?

Comment: What Griffiths technically did is he superposed the potential of an uncharged conducting sphere in a uniform field with the potential of a uniformly charged spherical shell to obtain the potential of the system in the question. @OfekGillon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maxwell equations are linear in the charges and the currents, meaning that if you superpose two sets of charges and currents, the fields will just add up. So, assuming that the charges causing your uniform field will not move due to the addition of extra charges, you can add up the uniform field with the field of your additional charges.
Important detail however is whether your sphere is conducting or not. In case of a non-conducting sphere, the uniform field will not lead to a rearrangement of your charges on the sphere, so you can superimpose the radial field of your sphere with the uniform field. If your sphere is conducting on the other hand, your charges will rearrange as correctly showed in your drawing.
For calculating the field caused by the charges on your conducting sphere, you need to start from Laplace's field equation for the electric potential in a spherical geometry, using separation of variables. As you have axial symmetry (no $\phi$ dependence), you only need to worry about the $r$ and $\theta$ dependence. The solutions to the differential equations for the $r$ and $\theta$ dependence need to be fitted to the boundary conditions, which are basically the condition the the potential caused by the sphere goes to zero as $r$ goes to infinity and the fact the electrical field should perpendicular to the sphere surface.

Comment: Thank you for your response (and sorry for the late comment). Is there any way to superpose simpler systems together to obtain the potential (see my comment under my post for the exact superposition used by Griffiths)?

Comment: The reasoning is as follows. Suppose you already have calculated the field of the uncharged conducting sphere in a uniform field. A uniformly charged sphere (charge Q) does generate a field that is zero inside the sphere and nonzero outside. So, if you superpose this field with the previous field, you get a field that satisfies the field equations (linearity), one that will account for the right amount of charge on the sphere (total charge Q) and that is zero in the sphere (required for a conducting sphere). So, as it satisfies all the requirements, it is a correct solution.